# Any way to get unigrams AND bigrams in my TDM with RTextTools?

Tags: r, package, classification, n-gram, tm

RTextTools is very handy if you want to compare algorithms for classifying text documents. there is an option: ngramLength with which one can specify, if one want to use 1-grams, 2-grams, 3-grams and so on. Now i'd like to have 1-grams AND 2-grams in my Term Document Matrix! is there a way to do that?

```
myTDM <- create_matrix(labeled$CLEAN, language="english", 
                    removeNumbers=FALSE, stemWords=FALSE, ngramLength=1,  
                    removePunctuation=FALSE, removeSparseTerms=0.98, 
                    removeStopwords=FALSE, stripWhitespace=FALSE, toLower=FALSE)
```

in another forum, i've seen "Tim J" (probably Tim Jurka, one of the creators of RTextTools) write that this functionality will be in a new version of RTextTools. He wrote it will probably be released in mid-January 2013. Now more than a year later, i wonder if there really is this new functionality and how it's used!

Thank You!!

Comment: I haven't used the package, but have you tried `ngramLength=c(1,2,3)`?
With a reproducible example we might be able to help more.

Comment: I voted to close this as there's no [Minimal Working Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you updated I'd rescind the vote to close.

Comment: there's no working example that would help answering this question. you can close it.

Comment: A workaround is to create one DTM for 1-grams, another one for 2-grams and `cbind` them as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993504/does-tm-package-itself-provide-a-built-in-way-to-combine-document-term-matrices/#46850328).